# Como atribuir uma class para um de outra Class

Tags: c#, classes

Em um programa eu criei uma class chamada `Player` e nela atribui vários valores, dentre eles há o valor de `Itens`.

Além desta class, existe outra class chamada `Itens` com atributos diferentes. Gostaria de saber como fazer para atribuir a class `Itens` ao valor `Itens` da class `Player`.

Ou seja todos os valores da class `Itens` iria para o atributo `Itens` da class `Player`.

Aqui está o meu código:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class Player
{
    public string nome;
    public int xp;
    public int gold;
    public Item();

}

public class Item
{
    public string nome;
    public int iD;
    public int preco;
}
public class LP2_Trabalho
{

    static List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        bool MostrarMenu = true;
        while (MostrarMenu)
        {
            MostrarMenu = MenuPrincipal();
        }
    }


    private static bool MenuPrincipal()
    {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Entre com '1' para criar um jogador (necessário para entrar na loja).");
        Console.WriteLine("Entre com '2' para checar as informações de todos os jogadores criados.");
        Console.WriteLine("Entre com '3' para olhar o seu inventário.");
        Console.WriteLine("Entre com '4' para entrar na loja.");
        Console.WriteLine("Entre com '4' para encerrar o programa.");

        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1":

                Console.Clear();  
                
                Console.Write("Digite o nome do seu jogador: ");
                var np = Console.ReadLine();
              
                Console.Write("Digite a quantidade de XP (experiência): ");
                var xpP = Console.ReadLine();
               
                Random randNum = new Random();
                var dinDin = randNum.Next(50, 200);


                Players.Add(new Player { nome = np, xp = Convert.ToInt32(xpP), gold = dinDin});
                Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Jogador criado com sucesso");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Verifique o seu gold (gerado de forma aleatoria): " + dinDin);
                Console.WriteLine("Tecle 'ENTER' para continuar...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return true;

            case "2":
                Console.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < Players.Count; i++)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("Jogadores:");            
                    Console.WriteLine("Nome : " + Players[i].nome);
                    Console.WriteLine("XP : " + Players[i].xp);
                    Console.WriteLine("Gold : " + Players[i].gold);                 
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.Write("Pressione qualquer tecla para sair...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return true;
            
            case "3":
                return true;

            case "4":
                return false;

            default:
                return true;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: POR FAVOR! Se a minha pergunta não for boa para o site me diga o que fazer! Eu já li o guia de sobrevivência e o outro artigo mostrando o porque a minha pergunta não está com boa qualidade. Além disso eu já tentei pesquisar no google o meu problema antes de vir aqui. Por favor não feche a minha pergunta :(

Comment: Olá Carlos. Tente nos mostrar a sua classe `Itens` que você disse na pergunta. Você citou que existe essa classe, porém não nos mostra como ela está criada. :)

Comment: @PedroPaulo desculpe por isso. Já consertei os problemas da pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta, você está criando um algoritmo (provavelmente para estudo) para simular um jogo. Você tem um jogador (Player) que pode ter um ou vários itens. Para isso você precisa que sua classe `Player` tenha uma coleção de itens.

```
public class Player
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Xp { get; set; }
    public int Gold { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Itens { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
}
```

Com isso em mãos, o que você precisa é criar um novo objeto `Item` e adicionar na lista de itens do player.

Por exemplo, na ação 1, onde você cria o seu `Player`, pode também criar um item e adicionar na lista.

```
Player player = new Player();

player.Nome = np;
player.Xp = Convert.ToInt32(xpP);
player.gold = dinDin;

// Aqui criamos um novo objeto item e definimos os valores dos seus campos
Item item = new Item();
item.Id = 10;
item.Nome = "Machado de pedra";
item.Preco = 100;

// Aqui associamos esse nosso novo item aos itens do nosso player
player.Itens.Add(item);

// Aqui adicionamos o nosso player na lista de players do jogo
Players.Add(player);
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado mesmo! É exatamente o que você disse. É um trabalho da escola e eu já tinha tirado duvidas demais com o professor e estava com medo de ser muito chato kkk. Obrigado!

Comment: Ótimo! Se a resposta lhe ajudou a resolver o problema, consegue votar como resposta aceita? Assim conseguimos mostrar para outras pessoas que essa resposta resolveu o seu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: eu não sabia dessa função. Coloquei a sua resposta!